# Optimizing TCP tuning

Tags: ethernet, sensors, tcp-ip

We have a platform that connects hundreds of sensors via Ethernet to an edge server operating on Ubuntu/Windows. Each frame size is 36kb. Our sensor side is developed using C and lwIP, while the server side is developed in Python. We conducted tests on both Windows and Linux. On the Windows version, we were able to achieve stable data transfer for 20 minutes. However, on the Ubuntu server, the server failed after receiving a couple of packets from the first frame. It appears that the server’s TCP configuration needs to be adjusted. Could you please advise on how to proceed with this configuration adjustment?

Comment: AskUbuntu is a Q&A site. Tutorials, which are inappropriate here, are available througj online searches.

Comment: What have you done to debug the issue? Do you have wireshark packet captures?